# Programatically get latest stable R release version number

Tags: r

How can I use R to get the most recent release of R?  I know about the `gtools::checkRVersion` but was hoping for a base solution, even better one that doesn't rely on scraping/regex.

The desired result as of today (2015-06-13) would be: `3.2.0`

Comment: How do you think this could be possible without checking CRAN?

Comment: @Roland I meant more that there was a CRAN sanctioned function to do this similar to `utils::available.packages` for checking packages.  Checking CRAN is fine.  It's more the regex that worries me in that CRAN may change how it displays a page, where as a function they've released is not likely to change.

Comment: I think CRAN mirrors have a way to get the latest release, whatever that may be. You could probably use that.

Comment: METACRAN offers an API: http://www.r-pkg.org/services

Comment: There is even a package wrapping the API, see the answer I just added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the METRCAN API (@Roland comment):

```
library(RJSONIO)
fromJSON("http://rversions.r-pkg.org/r-release")[[1]][['version']]
[1] "3.2.0"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another potential alternative: CRAN has a dcf file with version information. I'm not sure how reliably it is updated though.

```
R> tmp <- tempfile()
R> download.file("http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/VERSION-INFO.dcf", tmp)
R> (x <- read.dcf(tmp))
     Release Old-release Devel  
[1,] "3.2.0" "3.1.3"     "3.3.0"
```

Comment: This is great, useful for finding it out in any language.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new-ish package [rversions](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=rversions) by Gabor which wraps the service even more easily:

```
R> library(rversions)
R> r_release()
   version                        date
94   3.2.0 2015-04-16T07:13:33.144514Z
R> 
R> r_release()[[1]]
[1] "3.2.0"
R>
```

If you have [devtools](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=devtools) installed, you probably already have [rversions](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=rversions) too.

The package has two more functions to get

- the previous release via `r_oldrel()`, as well as
- a vector of all releases via `r_versions()`

Comment: This uses scraping/regex which what OP want to avoid

Comment: It calls a function _written for that exact purpose_ and that does work reliably.  If it is good for Hadley to depend upon, maybe it is good enough for others too. Moreover it goes to the **one** canonical source, the upstream SVN repo.